# Has Bruce Banner ever Hulked Out due to a nightmare?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

Has Bruce Banner ever transformed into the Hulk due to a nightmare or bad dream, and if he has, how does he stop himself from doing so every time he has a bad dream?

Comment: Its not exactly a nightmare, but in the Ang Lee film they try to get him angry but he resists, keeping his cool. So they try zapping him while he's asleep, which works and he Hulks out, thus implying that he was less control while asleep and can Hulk out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [1978 TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_(1978_TV_series)) (in the episode [Married, Part I](https://johnkennethmuir.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/cult-tv-flashback-98-the-incredible-hulk-married-1978/)), Bruce Banner has a nightmare. It would appear that this was sufficient to trigger a "hulk-out"

If memory serves, his ultimate resolution was that his sleep-hulking was being caused by his attempts to use hypnosis to "cage" the Hulk inside his mind. Once he stopped this treatment, his condition returned to normal.

Comment: Technically, this does not answer the question. The TV series featured *David* Banner. ;-)

Comment: @johnsensebe - Bruce was his middle name.

Comment: Valorum - Which he *never* used. When he saw it on his tombstone, he looked very upset.

Comment: @johnsensebe - It was still there, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example from the comics:

### Defenders Volume 1, Issue 21, March 1975

The Hulk was part of a loose group called the Defenders for years. The group was led by Dr. Strange.

In this issue, Dr. Banner arrives at Strange's Sanctum Sanctorum, after recently waking up in a nearby alley:

[image: Banner Arrives]

Strange is nice enough to put him up in a bed:

[image: Banner Sleeps]

But, across town, Gorilla Man injects some weird serum into Chondu the Mystic's brain, causing mystical nightmares across the city:

[image: Black Rain]

Unfortunately for the Defenders (and everyone else), Banner happens to be one of those "sleeping minds":

[image: Hulk Awakes]

Valkyrie bravely (foolishly) tries to stop the Hulk. Luckily, Chondu passes out before Hulk finishes smashing her:

[image: Hulk Sorry]

As to the second part of your question, "how does he stop himself from doing so every time he has a bad dream", this was not a normal dream. I'm working on reading all the Hulk comics, and I don't think I've seen him transform from a regular dream yet, but if I do I'll be sure to edit this answer.